# How to return server response via $service.save()

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJS and I have got this problem. I have got defined service `citiesService` with method `addCity`:

```
.service('citiesService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    this.addCity = function(city) {
        var cityItem = $resource("server/?module=cities&action=add", {}, {save: {method: "POST", isArray:true}});

        return cityItem.save({
            city: city
        });
    };
}])
```

It works fine, the new city was successfully added into DB via the PHP script, but I don't know, how to return server response. Server returning response like:

```
$output = [];
$output[] = ["success" => "added to database"];
echo json_encode($output);
```

and then I have got this controller:

```
.controller('citiesAddCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, citiesService) {           
    // save addCity form (modal)
    $scope.saveForm = function() {
        if($scope.city.name) {
            $scope.a = citiesService.addCity($scope.city);  
        }
    }
})
```

but I really don't know, how to display server JSON response. When I try something like `console.log($scope.a)`, It shown empty array, but as you can see, the server response is in the right debug menu:

[image]

Can you help me to solve this problem please? I read some Stackoverflow topics and tried some edits, which are described here, but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `save` returns a promise, you could access the response as following (untested):

```
.controller('citiesAddCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, citiesService) {           
    // save addCity form (modal)
    $scope.saveForm = function() {
        if($scope.city.name) {
            citiesService.addCity($scope.city).$promise.then(function(response) {
                $scope.a = response
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: `Error: citiesService.addCity(...).then is not a function` ... lots of peoples in Stackowerflow described similar solution, but it's not working for me

Comment: could you please try " citiesService.addCity($scope.city).$promise.then [...]"?

Comment: yeah, now I am playing with it and it seems to be working as I need! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simply $http which has a clear promise structure?

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "server/?module=cities&action=add",
  data: $scope.city

}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

See docs at [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)